# Angulrjs: A controller doesn't send a value via a factory with the "as" statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been teaching myself how to use the `as` statement of Angularjs's controller, but struggling to make controllers communicate with others, using the `as` syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('angularApp', [])
.factory('MessageService', function(){
    var message =  {
        addedItem: "initialMessge"
    };
    return {
        returnMessage: message//This is supposed to be the "var message" defined above
    };
})
.controller('DiaplayingProductController', function(MessageService){
    var instance = this;
    this.data = {
        message: MessageService.returnMessage.addedItem
    };
})
.controller('ProductController', function($scope, $http, MessageService) {
    var instance = this;
    this.data = {
        message: MessageService.message,
        //There are other stuff here
    };
    this.addItem = function(productName) {
        $http({
        //other tasks
        }).then(function addSucces(response) {
            instance.data.message.addedItem = productName;
        });
    };
});
```

```
<span ng-controller="DiaplayingProductController as dpc" ng-bind="dpc.data.message"></span>

    <div ng-controller="ProductController as pc">
        @foreach ($products as $index => $product)
        <div class="product">
            <button ng-click="pc.addItem({{$product->name}})>
                Add it to Cart
            </button>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

**I use Laravel, so `{{$product->name}}` and `@foreach` are Laravel's expression.**

In a nutshell,

1. There are one `<span>` and multiple `<button>`s, based on the result of `@foreach` (Again, I use Laravel, so this is basically the same thing as php's foreach)
2. When one of the `<button>` is pressed, the content of `<span>` is supposed to be updated.
3. The event is triggered in `ProductController`, which is supposed to update `message` of `DiaplayingProductController`, via `MessageService`.

The message is not going to be sent to the span tag.

This question may be silly. However, there are not many information resources out there which deal with this `as` statements, so I'd like to ask some advice here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to change your angular's `interpolation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's this `@foreach`?

There's a coma in your attributes. Shouldn't be there.

The expression in your `ng-click` has a missing parenthesis. Also, it should be an expression, therefore the `{{}}` have nothing to do here.

The `data` object are not shared between the controllers. You should:

1. use directives and pass the data using attributes ('=').
2. set the data in the $scope, which is not as good a solution
3. use a service as an intermediary (each controller can set/get the value
   from that service)

Comment: (your issue therefore has nothing to do with the "as" statement)

Comment: The `@foreach` is Laravel's expression, so this is the same as php's foreach loop. Thanks for your advice, I'll try that...!

Comment: oh, ok, so are the `{{}}` around `$product->name` are also part of Laravel? If so, that might be an issue as angular uses similar templating.